# How to draw an image of type Image using BufferedImage?

Tags: java, image

I am using BufferedImage to draw an image of type Image, but it's not getting drawn. Here's my code :

```
     Image tmp;
     BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(150,150,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
     Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
     currState=State.VICTORY;
      while(victoryst<=9)
    {
        tmp=victory[victoryst];
        victoryst++;
        g.drawImage(tmp, 150, 150, null);
     }
```

Comment: ok you've drawn onto the `BufferedImage` but do you draw the `bufferedImage` itself? Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is code to draw existing images in your victory array to a BufferedImage. All of the existing images are being painted to the same location, so they are going to overwrite each other. Otherwise, what is the problem? This code is not supposed to show anything on the screen

Comment: Actually I have done everything else with ImageIcon , hence for this one image I decided to do off with BufferedImage. Also with BufferedImage , I was having problems, as io.read wasn't working.. Anyways that's not the point. I am drawing it at the same location to give animation effect..But it's not getting displayed!!

Comment: *Of course* its not displayed. You're drawing to an *offscreen* image.

Comment: then? what is the solution?